# How to draw "clip" mask regions to a canvas, then draw content only where there are mask regions

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm finding some strange behavior when trying to handle a specific canvas drawing case. I have a selection of areas which I want to draw to ("mask areas"), defined as arbitrary polygons. I have some images/shapes/etc I then wish to draw, clipped to only draw into the masked areas.

I figured I could achieve this by:

- Filling the canvas with `(0, 0, 0, 0)` (with the handy `clearRect` method)
- Filling the mask areas with `(1, 1, 1, 1)`
- Setting the `context`'s `globalCompositeOperation` to `"multiply"`
- Drawing the content

(I'm trying to accomplish something similar, in effect, to GIMP's "Layer Mask" tool (filled with all-white), for those familiar.)

I'm aware I could handle this specific case using canvas clipping, but the task I wish to use this for would be made much simpler without it, and I figure doing it using multiplications should be possible. The *opposite* effect of what I'm aiming to achieve (drawing content and then blanking pixels afterwards) is fairly simple to do with a similar idea, using `globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"`, anyway.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head><style>
    html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

    body { margin: 0; width: 100%;
        height: 100%; background: #777; }

    canvas { border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px auto; display: block; }
</style></head>

<body><canvas id="can" width="1800" height="900"></canvas></body>

<script>
    const img = new Image;
    img.onload = () => requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
    img.src = "square.png";

    const canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    let then = 0;
    function drawFrame (now) {
        const deltaTime = now - then;
        then = now;

        // fill canvas with 0 in all channels
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // draw FPS
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.font = "16px serif";
        ctx.fillText(`FPS: ${Math.round(1 / (deltaTime / 1000))}`, 0, 16);

        // fill mask area with 1 in all channels
        ctx.fillStyle = "#01010101";
        ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 400, 400);

        // further draws should multiply current canvas values
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";

        // draw image (100*100 resolution image; half the image should be visible)
        // Each channel of each pixel **should** multiply together
        // "0"'d regions: 0 in all channels
        // "1"'d regions: 1 * imgChannelValue = imgChannelValue
        ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 100);

        // draw a box, which should have its top-left corner blanked
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
        ctx.strokeRect(300, 300, 500, 300);

        // (reset compositing)
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

And here's my high-quality `square.png` testing image:

[image].

Answer (score 0):

What you want is compositing, so don't try to use blending for it.

The compositing mode you seem to be wanting is `"source-in"`, which will keep the new content only where the destination already was painted.

So all you'll have to do, is to paint your mask area with full opacity, then switch the gCO to `"source-in"`, before drawing your image.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFJu0.png";

function draw() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  // draw the masking areas with full opacity
  drawShapes();
  // in a timeout just for demo
  setTimeout(()=> {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    // reset to default
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  }, 1000)
}

function drawShapes() {
  // draw some 'mask' shapes
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(130,20);
  ctx.arc(100, 20, 30, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.moveTo(10, 45);
  ctx.lineTo(60, 95);
  ctx.lineTo(8, 120);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillRect(40, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

But this will require that your "visible" drawings be merged as a single drawing call (this could be achieved by drawing them first on an offscreen-canvas).

So if you want, you can do the other way around: Draw all your "visible" drawings first, using source-over, then draw the "masking areas" as a single sub-path, using the `destination-in` compositing mode:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const urls = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFJu0.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"];

loadImages(urls).then(imgs => {
  // draw 'visibles'
  imgs.forEach((img) => ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
  // Now do the compositing
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  drawMasks();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

});

function drawMasks() {
  // draw your masks as a single sub-path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(130, 30);
  ctx.arc(100, 30, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.moveTo(30, 45);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 95);
  ctx.lineTo(38, 120);
  ctx.rect(40, 0, 20, 20);
  ctx.fill();
}

function loadImages(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(u => new Promise((res, rej) => Object.assign(
    (new Image()), {
      src: u,
      onload: e => res(e.target),
      onerror: rej
    }))))
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

And once again, if you can't merge all your 'masking areas' as a single sub-path, you can simply merge them before hand on an offscreen canvas, and draw this offscreen canvas in the compositing step.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this won't work. `"source-in"` only allows you to draw one shape/image after drawing the masks, right? I want to be able to draw an arbitrary number of images/shapes, each of which should be clipped to the same pre-drawn mask areas.